# error in import statement in reportlab

Tags: reportlab

I needed help in understanding the root of the following error.
While running a bar chart generating code in reportlab from the url https://www.reportlab.com/snippets/3/ ,I am facing an error on line

from standard_colors import pdf_chart_colors, setItems

stating that:

Import Error: No module named standard_colors

I dont understand whether there is a problem while installing reportlab or some thg else.
Please guide.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the standard_colors module.  Maybe it's something specific to ReportLab's commercial products?

Comment: I am no clue about that. But as you can see in the code they are using "setItems" and "pdf_chart_colors" in the code which is taken from standard_colors. If I dont use that, I dont know an alternative for the same.

Comment: Hmm, not sure then because I've never used those features in ReportLab (I've always needed more mathematical charting and used MatPlotLib).  Just try leaving that stuff out and see what happens:  you'll hopefully get something greyscale that you can then work on finding a way to colorize if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I got curious on this question and begin digging. There's a post stating what should be the standard_colors source code.

standard_colors.py:

```
from reportlab.lib.colors import HexColor 

pdf_chart_colors = [ HexColor("#0000e5"), HexColor("#1f1feb"), HexColor("#5757f0"), HexColor("#8f8ff5"), HexColor("#c7c7fa"), HexColor("#f5c2c2"), HexColor("#eb8585"), HexColor("#e04747"), HexColor("#d60a0a"), HexColor("#cc0000"), HexColor("#ff0000"), ] 

def setItems(n, obj, attr, values): 
    m = len(values) 
    i = m // n 
    for j in xrange(n): 
        setattr(obj[j],attr,values[j*i % m])
```

source: https://www.reportlab.com/snippets/3/